# refresh table using jquery without communicating database

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets

I am using [DataTable](http://datatables.net/api) jquery api for gridview. My sample is here under:

[image]

It shows the total numbers of entries in the following form at bottom

```
Showing 1 to 10 of 10 entries
```

My Delete code/script for this gridview using jquery is as follow:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('table#example td a.delete').click(function()
    {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this row?"))
        {
            $getCode = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
            var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
            $.post("DeleteDepartment", {
                depID:$getCode                   
            }, function(data) {
                if(data.result >0){
                    parent.fadeOut('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
                }else{
                    alert("Operation Fail");
                }
            });
        }
        else{
            $('div#feedback').html('<div class="cancel"><b>Operation Cancel</b></div>');

        }
    });
});
```

the above code successfully remove the record from the grid-view. but it does not shows the actual total no. of entries, after deletion.

for example, there are currently 10 records in the table , it shows in the bottom in the following format:

```
Showing 1 to 10 of 10 entries
```

when I remove the one entry , it must show the new total of entries

```
Showing 1 to 9 of 9 entries (total entry decrease by one, on every deletion )
```

**how can I refresh the table , without communicating Database** that reset total number of entries, showing left side of bottom, on every deletion

Answer (score 0):

Delete the row using the DataTable API.

http://datatables.net/api

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();

  // Immediately remove the first row
  oTable.fnDeleteRow( 0 );
} );
```

or in your case,

```
oTable.fnDeleteRow( $(this).index() );
```

assuming you used the same name for your dataTable data object.

**Edit**
Even better:

```
oTable.fnDeleteRow( this );
```

Comment: Dear, oTable.fnDeleteRow( 0 ) is working fine for the first row. but how can remove the selected row, because oTable.fnDeleteRow( $(this).index() ) and oTable.fnDeleteRow( this ) not working for me. I want to remove the selected row. @Kevin B

Answer (score 0):

Code, when click to last "td" -

http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/32737#Comment_32737

---

```
$("#ffetch tbody tr td:last-child").live('click', function(s) {
     var row = $(this).closest('tr');
     var nRow = row[0];
     $('#ffetch').dataTable().fnDeleteRow( nRow );
});
```